# Mysql. how to join two tables from this example?

Tags: mysql

everybody.
I have two requests.

1 query - show the list of dates with time 22:00 from one table

```
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(tt.create_time,"%Y-%m-%d 22:00:00") AS DAY,tt.id 
      FROM tick tt 
  GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(tt.create_time,"%Y-%m-%d")
```

2 query - shows the number of records that have create_time less than the date specified in the query

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM 
      (SELECT * FROM
         (SELECT * FROM tick_history th 
                  WHERE th.create_time < '2019-04-15 22:00:00' 
               ORDER BY th.id DESC)  AS t1 
       GROUP BY t1.tick_id) AS t2 
     WHERE t2.state NOT IN (1,4,9) AND t2.queue = 1
```

Is it possible to somehow combine these two queries to get one column with dates from the first query, and the second column is the number from the second query for each date from the first column? 
Ie as if substituted date and calculated the number of the second request..
Is it possible? Help with request please

Comment: Yes. use `UNION`

Comment: Your 1st query does not make sense. You select tt.id but you don't group by tt.id. This is a logical error and in other databases like SQL Server, Postgres, Oracle is not even allowed. I wonder which id you get as result from that query.

Comment: Could you show us a sample of your table data and your expected output?